# How to implement ssl security using client certificate in asmx web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, asmx

I am trying to create soap service using ASMX web service but I am facing problem in implementing SSL security using client certificate so that user can not consume service if he/she dont have certificate for security purpose. Is there any way to implement certificate authentication in app.config/web.config and also need help in creating URL like

**"https://www.customerA.com/NotifyCustomerA/CustAWithParams.asmx"**

Like WCF service we implement all security in bindings but in asmx can we implement this in same way or there is another way?.

Comment: why do u want to change the domain name cant you pass paramaeter?

Comment: because user wants that way. I don't have choice.